# How distribute a GIF file with activityVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, gif, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a project which create a GIF file.

I want to know how could i share/distribute this file with activityView.

Example: Save in library , share to facebook, twitter, messages or e-mail?

I already tried with this  [project](https://github.com/yangyubo/OWActivityViewController) but it's just send a image.

Can somebody help me, maybe give me another project which can share this file and  some instructions for use will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

```
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
        NSURL *fileURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"animated.gif"];




        NSString *text = @"Text";
        NSData *gifFile=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileURL.path];
        UIActivityViewController *controller =
        [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
         initWithActivityItems:@[text,gifFile]
         applicationActivities:nil];


        controller.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                             UIActivityTypePrint,
                                             UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                             UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                             UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                             UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                             UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                             UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                                             UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                             UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to use `UIActivityViewController` to share the gif file.

Comment: Take a look  now. It's just sharing a image.

Comment: Instead of passing the `NSDate` of the image, pass a `UIImage`.

Comment: And why do you exclude some many activities? You are sharing an image. Let the user do most of the things in your exclusion list.

Comment: UIImage it's distribute just a jpg file.

Comment: Use this code :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007067/ios-share-gif-animated-image-not-working/44041180#44041180

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to find that it works via Messages, but not via other UIActivity types such as Twitter.

I took this to mean that I was attaching the GIF correctly, but for example, the Twitter UIActivity was not accepting GIFs (and was instead just posting a still from the GIF).

I created SBBAnimatedTweetActivity to get around this limitation - it's available on GitHub - feel free to use it as a Cocoapod, or fork it for yourself.
https://github.com/siburb/SBBAnimatedTweetActivity